# Generate certificate for HTTP service from Istio

Tags: elasticsearch, ssl, istio

Is it possible to generate certificates via Citadel for HTTPS services? In my case, I would like to use the Elastic ECK operator to spawn a new Elasticsearch cluster + Kibana, but I don't want to use the self-signed CA (since I'd have to push that CA certificate file to all and every service that wants to connect to the ES API); rather I'd like to use another self-signed certificate authority; the one and the same that Istio uses.

My hope is that if we get around to adding Vault to the cluster + cert-manager, I can easily create new certificates with that and all HTTPS usage **INSIDE** the cluster.

How can I (or can I), generate TLS certificates with Istio somehow? I have SDS installed in the cluster.

This question is **not** about:

- How to generate *public* certificates
- cert-manager
- How to turn off TLS in Elasticsearch's HTTP endpoint

Comment: Did you have chance to test [Chiron](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/cert-management/dns-cert/) in this role, which appeared in Istio 1.4 ?

Comment: I did not, but I did discover that Istio allows mounting its mTLS certificates into the pod it has a side-car for, as a volume(s). That API is the same in the latest version; Chiron is just another CA as far as I understand.

Comment: For the CA role in Chiron, I think it's handed over to the existing CA, the Kubernetes CA.

Comment: Ok, I see, you decided to re-use TLS certificate from sidecar, where it's mounted by SDS. I think this feature is considered to be experimental, and its usage was described in the blog post [here](https://istio.io/latest/blog/2020/proxy-cert/) (cert mounted in tmpfs).